# JS formData.append does nothing

Tags: javascript

So, when i try to append a data to a formData, it does nothing.
**Js code:**

```
document.querySelector("#regForm").addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let username = document.querySelector("#username").value;

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', 'username');
    console.log(formData)
    
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", '/register');
    request.send(formData);
})
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Edit: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAGs6.png)

Comment: what part 'does nothing'?

Comment: So, i append the data and console.log it. And the console says that: FormData: {}

Comment: As Ankit jain says, `console.log(formData.get('username'));` works

Comment: Im going to put a screenshot to the question

Comment: I don't use VS Code, but it looks like you're running an old version of the code.  It looks like you didn't stop the server and start it again after the code change.

Comment: Its the newest, and its running with nodemon but it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`FormData.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries)

Since `FormData.entries` return iterator

You can transform it to array using [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

If you want the result to be object you need to use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function

```js
const formData = new FormData()

formData.append('username', 'username')
formData.append('password', 'password')

const result = [...formData.entries()].reduce((acc, val) => {
  acc[val[0]] = val[1]

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

check this formData.get('username') // "username"
it is working

Comment: I check it already, its working.